# Python SMS Twilio Script Having to Go Through Proxy Wall

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I began using Twilio for Python3 today and I found it quite difficult to even get the first basic script to work.

**send_sms.py**

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "your_account_sid"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="+15558675309", 
    from_="+15017250604",
    body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

send_sms.py is the first program that the Twilio "Getting Started" panel asks me to test out. The problem is that I have a proxy network with a username, password, and proxy site. Without this connection, I get the ConnectionRefusedError. I realized after a few tests that failure to connect to the proxy network meant a failed program. I am aware of using ProxiedTwilioHttpClient() as a possible solution but have absolutely no idea how to implement it.

What I am asking for is how to add proxy network authentication to the above code sample. I can use the sample for future reference for other particular programs. If you have any questions, please feel free to add a comment below.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to pass in a custom HttpClient, like this:

```
import os

from requests import Session

from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import HttpClient

proxy_server = 'http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:80'

ProxySession = Session()
ProxySession.proxies.update({'http': os.environ.get('http_proxy', proxy_server)})

ProxyClient = HttpClient()
ProxyClient.session = ProxySession

account_sid = 'xxx'
account_token = 'xxx'

client = Client(account_sid, account_token, http_client=ProxyClient)
```

Comment: Ok and after the client I can write the rest of the code in my question?

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: I can't tonight because I am actually just about to get into bed but if I come across a problem, may I contact you? If no problems occur I will just hit the check mark.

Comment: Hi Burhan. This is the error I get: https://github.com/Jrachman/debug/blob/master/errorsend_sms.